# c++ static and dynamic type casting

Tags: c++, dynamic-cast, static-cast

Why `static_cast<>()` (also known as downcast) doesn't casts types run-time while `dynamic_cast<>()` (also known as upcast) does? Both are used to advance through class hierarchy. What could be so different between them that it is necessary for `dynamic_cast<>()` to cast types run-time?

Comment: You have the wrong angle on this: they behave that way because that is what they are designed to do.

Comment: I think you switched the two __cast terms, but `static_cast` is used for way more than upcasting. Yes, they could be switched, but I've never seen a `dynamic_cast` do upcasting. `static_cast` used for downcasting is generally found more in things like CRTP.

Comment: You are not showing any research effort whatsoever.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both are usually used for downcasting (from a base to a derived class); upcasting is always safe, so doesn't need an explicit cast. As noted in the comments, both are equivalent (and equivalent to an implicit conversion) if you use them for upcasting.

For downcasting, `static_cast` is faster but potentially dangerous, since it doesn't perform a runtime check and gives undefined behaviour if the conversion is not valid. It also works with non-polymorphic types, while `dynamic_cast` requires the run-time type information that's only available from polymorphic types.

Your introductory book should cover this in detail.

Comment: There's an implicit conversion for upcasting, but there may be times you want an explicit conversion.  In such cases, `dynamic_cast` and `static_cast` are synonyms.